# JobInsertionContent iFacts.getRoute.getStart().getLocation() is null

Tags: jsprit

I'm trying to implement a HardActivityConstraint which chooses services/shipments that lie in a certain radial distance from the vehicle depot.

In the constraintStatus method, I am trying to get the start location of the route from the JobInsertionContext but it always has value null.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `newVehicle.getStartLocation()` instead since `iFacts.getRoute.getStart().getLocation()` might change with the newVehicle, and it might be null if no vehicle has been assigned to this route yet.